# How to implement sorting on a list of dynamic strings with Name and Value

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I gave my best shot at a title for this question, but hopefully the explanation will be enough.

Right now I have an object that gets populated for a dynamically created table. This object looks like this:

```
public class RowData
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }

    public RowData(string name, string value)
    {
        Name = name;
        Value = value;
    }
}
```

I have a `List<List<RowData>>` that I pass back to my front end and get populated in a table. The idea being that it is a list of rows and then a list of each rows column data.

I am looking to implement a way to sort the data by the column selected in my table. My initial thought was that I would be able to achieve something like this by using reflection on the name property and then sorting by its corresponding value property.

However, I am seem to be stumped... and perhaps need to think about a better way to implement this.

Lets say I have data like so added into my `List<List<RowData>> rowData = new List<List<RowData>>();`:

```
var col1 = new RowData() { Name = "Col1", Value = "123"};
var col2 = new RowData() { Name = "Col2", Value = "ABC" };
var col3 = new RowData() { Name = "Col3", Value = "Some Test" };

var col4 = new RowData() { Name = "Col1", Value = "456" };
var col5 = new RowData() { Name = "Col2", Value = "DEF" };
var col6 = new RowData() { Name = "Col3", Value = "Another Test" };

var row1 = new List<RowData>() { col1, col2, col3 };
var row2 = new List<RowData>() { col4, col5, col6 };

rowData.Add(row1);
rowData.Add(row2);
```

If I pass a string like `Col1` how could a programmatically sort `rowData` by `Value` that are corresponds to `Name` that equals `Col1`? Or do I need to entirely rethink my process here?

If I passed the string of `Col1` the anticipated outcome would be something like:

| Co11 | Col2 | Col3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | ABC | Some Test |
| 456 | DEF | Another Test |

If I passed the string of `Col3` the anticipated outcome would be something like:

| Co11 | Col2 | Col3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 456 | DEF | Another Test |
| 123 | ABC | Some Test |

Comment: FWIW, there's already a [DataTable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.datatable?view=net-7.0) type that represents the concept you're trying to achieve. You might find it helpful.

Comment: Are you looking to sort the data in-place (reordering the original `rowData` collection), or are you okay creating a new collection that represents the reordered data?

Comment: @StriplingWarrior - I don't feel strongly either way. Really just looking for the better implementation of this and avoid any bad code smells from an architectural standpoint. I already feel like I am going down a bad path lol.

Comment: `RowData` is basically `KeyValuePair<string, string>`, with Key = Name and Value = Value. So the simplest fix would be to turn `List<List<RowData>>` into `List<Dictionary<string, string>`. Sorting becomes as simple as `rowData.OrderBy(x => x["Col1"])`.

Comment: will all rows always have the exact same valued list columns?

Comment: The naming is painful to read. You create a `RowData` object and name it `col1`. Then you create a `List<RowData>` and name it `row1`. Then you create a `List<List<RowData>>` and name it `rowData`. The variable name should just follow the class name. e.g. `var rowData1 = new RowData { Name = "Col`", Value = "123" }`

Comment: @RJ - really productive comment. Thank you for that... Cause in no way could this just be pseudocode with names made up on the fly, right? Move on.

Comment: @Schmid - Your suggestion does work. And might provide a simpler solution. However it is worth noting for any future people that stumble upon this that your solution only works if you assign it to a new variable list. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To directly answer the question, you can sort the initial list like this:

```
string colName = "Col3";
rowData.Sort((rd1, rd2) => rd1.First(c => c.Name == colName).Value.CompareTo(rd2.First(c => c.Name == colName).Value));
```

Or you can leave the original list alone and created a new sorted list like this:

```
var sorted = rowData.OrderBy(rd => rd.First(c => c.Name == colName).Value)
    .ToList();
```

Depending on your use case you may want to consider using different data structures to represent your data. If you have a lot of columns, it might make sense to represent each row as a Dictionary for quick lookup by name. Or you might consider using the DataTable type directly, although that might be overkill--it's got a lot of handy features, but it's slower than many other options because it tries to do so many things.

Comment: Thank you! This does directly answer my question and helped!